# Should I make wrappers for polymorphic classes that need to be allocatd on the heap?

Tags: c++

Right now, the GUI API for games I''m developing has an abstract Image and Font class. Depending on whether they use a GL, SDL etc Font, they load fonts like this:

```
Font *segoe = Font::load("segoe.ttf");
```

There is also a corresponding destroy() static function as well.

I like this design, but I was wondering if it would be a good idea to wrap it so that no pointers needed. Something like this (with better naming conventions)

```
WrappedFont segoe = WrappedFont(Font::load("segoe.ttf"));
```

It would also have overloaded = and a copy ctor, and a destructor.

Is it generally more desired for a game gui for the user to manage their Images and Fonts, or is a wrapped pattern more desirable?

Thanks

Comment: What would `WrappedFont` add? Would it act as a smart pointer?

Comment: @delman it would only be able to be allocated on the stack thus self managed in the scope of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, that's a custom smart pointer type to handle the `load/destroy` logic. This is very idiomatic and the way to go in C++. Resource management should be automatic.

So your wrapper is fine, but perhaps you are reinventing the wheel here. You may consider rewriting the font system that the work done by `destroy` is moved to the `Font` destructor, in which case you could use a regular `boost::shared_ptr` (also available from `std` in C++0x respectively `std::tr1` in older compilers with support for the Technical Report 1). With your current code you can use `shared_ptr` as well, but you need to supply a custom deleter, which I find a bit cumbersome.

Comment: What if more than one wants to use the same Bitmap or Font though?

Comment: I tried to elabore a bit. basically you should take a look into smart pointers in general and perhaps one of the flavours of `shared_ptr` in detail. It handles shared instances internally and leaves no worries to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the way to go. Minor point: why not just have

WrappedFont segoe = WrappedFont("segoe.ttf");

You don't need to expose every detail to the user. The simpler it is, the fewer errors. If they really need to know the font involved, add a Font getFont() method.

Answer (score 0):

This is always a personal choice. If you decide to allocate in constructor/init methods and destroy in destructor then it's a good idea (for that you have `shared_ptr<>` also.

But be informed that, if it's polymorphic then the virtual calls outside the class scope will be something like,

```
WrappedFont segoe = WrappedFont(Font::load("segoe.ttf"));
seogoe.getFontPtr()->VirtualFunction();  // more text !
```

Answer (score 0):

You could yes, but the idea is to simplify the user life.

I usually introduce 2 classes for this:

- `Font`: a base non-virtual class, which acts as a wrapper and resource manager and delegate the calls to an implementation (internal)
- `FontInterface`: a pure interface

Customization comes by deriving from `FontInterface` and then somehow hooking into `Font`. In the case where I have full control over the code, I usually ask that an enum member be added for each derived class, the constructor for `Font` switches on this `enum` to instantiate the right derived class.

This is, indeed, a mix of `Strategy` and `Factory` pattern:

```
class Font
{
public:
  enum Type { Segoe };

  explicit Font(Type type);

  void call1() const { _impl->call1(); }
  void call2() const { _impl->call2(); }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<FontInterface> _impl;
};
```

What's really interesting here is that the interface is stable in the face of redesign (for the user). The fact that there is an internal implementation which depends from the font selected is completely hidden.

Indeed, it is easy enough to move toward a `FlyWeight` pattern, for in the case of fonts the `Font` itself is normally stateless, only specifying behavior. Just change the `std::unique_ptr` for a `std::shared_ptr`, and have a simple cache system to maintain in memory the currently loaded fonts (using `weak_ptr`) and hand them over as necessary.